# IdeaVim - How to use vertical bar for normal mode?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, ideavim, goland

It uses block cursor for command mode and a vertical bar for insert/replace mode, how can I use vertical bar for both mode?
I removed  `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Use block caret` option, but the behavior had not changed.

Comment: Feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM.